# 90° twist while attacking in Cosmoteer

Tags: perspective

Using a custom ship design (semi-red) some notice a 90° degree twist of the planned final melee-position to the target (light-red).

[image]

The spiky nose *should* point to the target. Instead a 90° degree angle clockwise is calculated.

On the ship there are only weapons on the spiky nose, no weapons on the side.

Why is that / How to fix that?